# Windows 7 replication with consumer NAS

Tags: replication

This question has a few bits to it, so I'll try and lay down what I want, what I have and hopefully you can provide the what will make it work.

I have several laptops, and would like the all to synch with a consumer nas when switched on, or when they connect to the network after being worked on awway from it.

I use Visual studio as my primary application, I mention this because it is constantly making small changes to files.

I run Windows 7 ultimate on all machines.

Things I have installed: Dropbox, Live mesh (+skydrive) Office 2010 and sharepoint designer.

I'm a tad baffled. Dropbox would have been perfect but there are issues in Visual Studio and/or dropbox where files are constantly changed a little.

I've asked something similar over on SO, but it occured to me this might be a better place, so first post here :D

THank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up folder redirection through GPO and have the redirected folders sit on the NAS. If you configure Offline Files, then the behavior will be exactly what you are looking for. The users will be working on local copies when disconnected and copies on the NAS when connected.

Comment: Brilliant. What is GPO?

Comment: @Ian Group Policy Objects